# Does the theorem on transpose of a matrix extend to same dimension matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my textbook this theorem is stated on transpose of a matrix:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times m$ matrices, $C$ an $m \times k$ matrix, and $s$ a scalar. Then

(a)$(A+B)^T = A ^T +B^T$

(b)$(sA)^T =sA^T$

(c)$(AC)^T =C^TA^T$

However, they don't mention about $(AB)^T$, where $A$ and $B$ are of the same dimensions.

Since (c), would $(AB)^T$ simply be $B^TA^T$?

If not, is there another equivalency for $(AB)^T$?

Thank you.

Comment: What is stopping you from taking $m = n = k$?

Comment: Multiplication of matrices takes into account it's dimensions. Maybe transpose of a matrix also has some restrictions or rules concerning dimensions I might not know of.

Comment: The above says **for every** $k,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$. It doesn't say that they have to be different.

Comment: The theorem doesn't address $(AB)^T$ because (a priori, unless $n=m$) there is no $AB$; you can't multiply matrices of non-matching dimensions.

Comment: @JonathanY. You're right. I foolishly assumed that the OP meant square matrices of the same order.